# React-mdl scroll on click not working ... window.scrollTo is disable

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I am trying to implement a scroll on click for my menu so that once you click a tab then it goes that to the element in a single page application, but it seems with react mdl this function is disable, any idea of how to implemente a scroll onClick?

I´ve tried using a few libreries such as react-scroll

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can add some code of your implementation of ```react-scroll```, and perhaps where you call that method.

Comment: I think that You must add `id` to component <MyElement id={"your_id_element"} /> and after get handler co element and scroll to them. But without code is some hard